# Custom User Dashboard

Tags: custom-field, dashboard, plugin-recommendation, user-registration

I want to create a user dashboard that displays certain elements.

To understand what i'm saying, allow me to give you a quick background.

First of all i'm not a pro and it's my first time building a website and asking you guys here so please go easy on me and teach me because i want to learn.

Secondly, my website (i can't share the details because it's still under construction). Contains a page called "Page of Order" i offer my clients a service. So in the page they are presented with a simple form to fill,

1. Full Name
2. E-Mail
3. and other characteristics regarding my service (brief, etc...)

Hopefully you get the picture now.

**So my main question is this**

**QUESTION** : I want to create a simple user dashboard which they will be redirected at after they fill and purchase my service and the dashboard should display the following:
**My Orders** : view or modify the status of the order or orders if they have more than one
**Order Now** : takes them to the page of order only this time they don't have to login again

And other basic stuff such as
My Profile and My Account if they want to edit their Info.

---> Hopefully i was descriptive about my problem.
I'm seeking your help, for the Record, as i already stated above, i'm not a pro and i use Elementor to build my website.

I don't mind a little bit of code but i'm afraid i will mess or break the site. So if you know a Plugin that can solve my problem i will be so grateful.

Thanks in advance

**EDIT: I'm using Wordpress**

Comment: Are you using WordPress or its a custom application?

Comment: Yes i'm using Wordpress

Comment: Then you can use woocommerce to sell your package and it has a inbuilt user dashboard feature.

Comment: Oh really? I didn't thought of that, can i customize the dashboard though?

Comment: sure. Its too easy. Just create a page and use the default shortcode that is shipped with woocommerce and you are done. And for customizations you can create functions an d hook them in your theme functions.php file.

Comment: Thank you sooo much i really appreciate your time and effort